# Why does the ginger wither at the top/tip?

Tags: vegetables, plant-health, ginger

I have been growing culinary ginger quite successfully however there are times when one or two stems start drying out at the top/tip and I don't know what could be the cause. The ginger are planted near the window and not exposed to direct sunlight. Would be great if someone could advice, thanks!

[image: ginger plant]

Comment: How big is the container this is growing in (height, width and depth or a photo showing it and the soil within please) What part of the world are you in?

Comment: 45cm length, 35 cm width, 15 cm depth. Potting mix. Im in southeast Asia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've only got one piece of ginger root in that size pot, the pot's too large, but if there's more than one growing, fine.

Usual cause of this problem is dry air, that is, low air humidity, or erratic watering or poor drainage. They like free draining soil which is moist, but not waterlogged. If you have air conditioning, that could cause this problem, or if you let the soil dry out too much, but otherwise, if it's just the occasional tip, it's not really a problem.